# Permission dialog is not showing in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-library

I am using [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) for camera permission in my app. When user clicks on a button I want to check a permission, but when I am clicking on the button, no permission is checked.

Below is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PermissionListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    choose.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"HEllo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            .withListener(this)
    }
}

override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
    permission: PermissionRequest?,
    token: PermissionToken?
) {

}

override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse?) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call .check() while requesting the permission

```
Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            .withListener(this).check()
```

Comment: Thanks bro I forgot to add check().One more thing when I denied then dialog does not show  when I click button again.

Comment: let me check please

Comment: @Digvijay .. call `PermissionToken.continuePermissionRequest()` in `onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown()`